# How to use REFERENCES statement with Custom Type in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have this code:

```
Create TYPE Umpire As OBJECT(UmpireID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
UmpireName VARCHAR2(50),UmpireAddress VARCHAR2(50),  UmpireContact VARCHAR2(50),
MEMBER FUNCTION get_results RETURN VARCHAR2,
MEMBER PROCEDURE set_results
(UmpireID INTEGER,UmpireName VARCHAR2(50),UmpireAddress VARCHAR2(50),UmpireContact VARCHAR2(50));

Create table Certificate(UmpireId INTEGER,CertificateUpdated CHAR, FOREIGN KEY (UmpireId) REFERENCES Umpire(UmpireId));
```

I have this error: "Schema Creation Failed: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist"

How to use REFERENCES statement with Custom Type in Oracle?

Comment: `Umpire` is a type, it has no data, so how can a foreign key reference it? What you have is no more valid than `REFERENCES INT (SomeID)`

Answer (score 0):

FOR refernce purpose you need to use below syntax.

```
CREATE TABLE parent (
id INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE child (
id INT, 
parent_id INT,
INDEX par_ind (parent_id),
FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) 
    REFERENCES parent(id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Also, if attempting to access a table or view in another schema, make certain the correct schema is referenced and that access to the object is granted.

Are you trying to run both the select and the insert from the same Database User? Can you show us the session in SQLPLUS from Connect to disconnect? Can you show the definition of the Function?

If you created a table in Schema A and the function in Schema B, you should take a look at Oracle's Invoker/Definer Rights concepts to understand what might be causing the issue.

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/subprograms.htm#LNPLS00809

I hope this will help.